# Comparing TEXT variables doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm running into problems when I try to compare TEXT on my Android SQLite DB.

I have a query like that:

```
select * from myTable where _id='some.text.dots.are.really.there!'
```

myTable is `TEXT PRIMARY KEY`. I'm trying to select and update some data in my table. There are there and get returned when I do a SELECT *.

The Android code (with where clause) looks like that:

```
mDb.query(TABLE_TRANSACTIONS, TABLE_TRANSACTIONS_COLUMNS, COLUMN__ID + " = ?", 
            new String[] {id }, null, null, null);
```

But

```
mDb.query(TABLE_TRANSACTIONS, TABLE_TRANSACTIONS_COLUMNS, COLUMN__ID + " = '" + id + "'", 
            null, null, null, null);
```

works neither. How do I compare TEXT values in SQLite on Android?

Comment: Both should work, I would double check your ids in the debugger to see if the really do match.

Comment: They do match. The thing is: I'm getting the id from the DB and trying to update it some place later  in the code and there it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, please post the code where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem: The routines are salting the IDs and therefore they differ from the plain text string.

Stupid error ... Anyways, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite also considers the `TEXT CASE` (UPER CASE/LOWER CASE) while comparing string, so you can use `COLLATE NOCASE`, which forces SQLite to ignore `TEXT CASE`.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   myTable 
WHERE  _id='some.text.dots.are.really.there!' 
COLLATE NOCASE;
```

You can use rawQuery for SELECT:

```
mDb.rawQuery('Query Here',null);
```

and executeQuery for INSERT/UPDATE/DELET:

```
mDb.executeQuery('Query Here',null);
```